# Plumbing/Electric in same sleeve

Tags: electrical

Can a plumbing drain and an electric wire be run in the same 4" sleeve between floors. Not sure of code requirements.

Comment: should always separate electricity from water!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a requirement to separate them & haven't had an Inspector ever say anything, they always cross paths & run the same path somewhere. Of course, separate would be best for everything.

The only possible Code that might be violated is a floor penetration that isn't fire blocked & sealed. Depends if it was done prior to that part of The Code.

You can stuff (tightly pack) it with Rockwool or Mineral-Wool Insulation to address that for big gaps. Fire Caulk burns, but The Code has it as it's blocking of choice for small gaps or an overall smear seal of everything...the thicker the better with that stuff.

Comment: I would say yes the can be in the same space, and believe that is your answer.+

Comment: Thanks for the backup. I don't recall even a rumor that they couldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

There should be stud guards at the base and top plates to protect both from trim board and gypsum nails.  Other than that as mentioned by Iggy, some approved insulation would be good especially if it is a large hole.